# How anonymous is my activity using my specific VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ipv6, privacy

I am using a VPN with the following OpenVPN-configuration on Windows 10:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn-us.premiumize.me 1194
cipher AES-128-CBC
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
verb 3
auth-user-pass userpass.txt
reneg-sec 0
```

But sites like http://test-ipv6.com/ show next to the VPN's IPv4-Address the same IPv6-Address that it shows when I don't use a VPN. It also detects my Country and my ISP correctly.

Also `tracert 2a00:1450:400e:806::200e` using with de-/activated VPN gives both the same output.

How can I make sure my traffic is tunnelled correcty and my activity hidden from my ISP and other potentially interested parties?

Comment: It sounds like your VPN provider is not supporting IPV6 but your ISP is - either that or they have misconfigured the remote end not to push a default route. 

Try disabling IPV6 and see what happens.  Also, have a look at the default gateway on your Windows box and see if its going through the tunnel interface - your provider might not be setting a default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Most VPN providers don't handle IPv6 properly (e.g. by directing IPv6 traffic into the VPN or alternately by blocking it). This includes some that have (seemingly undeserved) reputations for privacy and anonymity.

It's a bit ridiculous that you would purchase a VPN but nearly half of your traffic doesn't even go over it!

If your provider offered you a trial period or money back guarantee, now is the time to cancel and get your money back. It will take a *lot* of shopping around to find a VPN provider who gets this right.